# Scraping links from results

Tags: php, screen-scraping

Where is the problem with this simple code:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.google.com/search?q=newyork');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query("//h3/a/@href");
foreach($entries as $e) {
  echo $e->textContent . '<br />';
}
?>
```

when I run I get only white window (nothing). Is problem with google?

Comment: Remove the `@` and activate error reporting to see possible errors

Comment: I changed and remove @ but still doesnt work and also add a libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

Comment: it's probally problem with google?

Comment: Your code works for me without any modifications (tested in command-line mode), printing 21 links from the search result page.

Comment: but I in chrome get only white window. WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some advice, continuing on [this related answer by Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756168/getting-information-from-google-calendar-using-phps-domdocument#6756259):

Try getting the HTML with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$google_results = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/search?q=newyork');
$dom->loadHTML($google_results);
```

If `file_get_contents()` fails as well, make sure [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled in your configuration (php.ini), or consider fetching the remote data using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Anyway, with error reporting enabled PHP should show you some errors or warnings, which is always helpful when something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: ok, thanks but: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 3 in /home/someurl/public_html/google1.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : br in Entity, line: 5 in /home/someurl/public_html/google1.php on line 5

Comment: Those are the warnings you're suppressing with the `@` operator in your original code. They are most likely due to invalid HTML (Google isn't very strict about HTML validity). But `DOMDocument` can usually deal with that. Make sure the HTML is fetched correctly (e.g. `echo $google_results;`). If it is, you need to try to figure out why traversing the DOM tree fails. Try something simpler first (e.g. `$headings = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h3');
foreach ($headings as $heading) echo $heading->nodeValue."\n";`).

Comment: I'm trying everithing but I have no idea what is the problem! THANKS ALL FOR HELP!!!